# Node rss reader indefinitely

Tags: node.js, rss, rss-reader

I am trying to do a non-stop rss reader with the ortoo-feedparser module.

What is the simplest solution to check the new feed every x minutes ? Do I need a database ?

This is my code :

```
var feedparser = require('ortoo-feedparser');

var url = "website.com/rss.xml";

feedparser.parseUrl(url).on('article', function(article){
    console.log(article.title);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// In minutes
var intervalTime = x * 60 * 1000;

// To start polling
var interval = setInterval(pollingFunc, intervalTime);

// To finish polling
clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: I only want the new feeds :/